# Naming a function for provided localized strings

Tags: html, asp-classic, localization

I'm putting together a list of function names for a function which would return back a localized string for a website I am working on.  I'm still undecided what would be a good name for this function.  My two goals are two try and make it as short as possible as I will have to replace tons of hardcoded text embedded in HTML but make it intuitive enough that new developers would understand what it is meaning.  In many ways I think this is a personal preference but I am curious to hear what all of you folks would do.

Here's some example function calls of what I am looking at right now...

```
// This would return "Hello" for english, "Bonjour" for french
LangString("Hello")

// Same as above just different function name
LSTR("Hello")
```

I am working in HTML and embedded classic ASP/VBscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `tr` for translate. It's short, doesn't muddle the context too much, and it has a pretty universal meaning.

Qt and Unix use `tr`, at any rate, so it's not really a proprietary naming scheme.

Comment: I like the shortness of it.  Just realized this may be an issue as I am working with vbscript embedded in html.  Could get confused with a <tr> tag.  I forgot to mention this in my original post so you wouldn't have known that.  I have since corrected!

Comment: Meh, I'd still use tr. Wordiness in something so common would really get to me.

Comment: Yeh you could be right.  I'm going to think it over.  Thanks for the suggestion.